# High Resolution Mineral Maps

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Australia has recently published high resolution surface mineral maps using data from ASTER [see here](http://www.csiro.au/Organisation-Structure/Flagships/Minerals-Down-Under-Flagship/Exploration/Project-ASTER-overview.aspx). Does anyone know of similar free products available world-wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US government portal for this data is **mrdata** from from USGS:
[Mineral Resources On-Line Spatial Data](http://mrdata.usgs.gov/).
They also include some [world maps](http://mrdata.usgs.gov/general/?place=fLD) with a list of [external databases](http://mrdata.usgs.gov/general/index.php?place=fBL&div=fips).

In particular you may be interested in the [Mineral Resources Data System](http://mrdata.usgs.gov/mrds/) (MRDS).

[image]

In addition to interactive maps, they also offer a list of [API web-services](http://mrdata.usgs.gov/catalog/api.php).

Just a couple of the services:

- [Data records near a geographic location](http://mrdata.usgs.gov/catalog/api.php?id=3)
- [Data catalog records for a topic category](http://mrdata.usgs.gov/catalog/api.php?id=6)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Phil's answer I have found two other resources.

[GLiM](https://www.geo.uni-hamburg.de/en/geologie/forschung/geochemie/glim.html) is a 0.5 degree grid of surface rock properties.  The categories here are very broad,

AD Alluvial deposits

DS Dune sands

EV Evaporites

etc.

There is also [OneGeology](http://www.onegeology.org/) which is a collection of geological surveys from different countries that can be viewed in a single portal.  The drawback of OneGeology is that there is no single file format with consistent fields and scale etc.  It is just a collection of separate resources.

Comment: You can contact each of the onegeology data providers and ask for the  raw data.

Comment: GLiM appears to have moved. New link here: https://www.geo.uni-hamburg.de/en/geologie/forschung/geochemie/glim.html