# Geology/mineral dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset that relates the location of minerals or other valuable resources like gold or oil to the geological conditions in which they occur. So for example for a certain location, it could have the surface pressure, temperature, soil info, etc. Where can I find something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High Resolution Mineral Maps](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/high-resolution-mineral-maps)

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to combine multiple datasets to get what you are looking for here. As mentioned in [High Resolution Mineral Maps](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/high-resolution-mineral-maps), you can find some of this information in the [USGS Mineral Resources Data API](https://mrdata.usgs.gov/catalog/api.php), including mineral availability (by region, resource, or boundary) and some geologic and soil conditions.

The [NOAA datasets](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access), particularly the [paleoclimatology datasets](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/paleoclimatology-data), may fill in some of the climate related data (present or historical) that you mentioned.

You may also find the [Global Lithological Map](https://www.geo.uni-hamburg.de/en/geologie/forschung/geochemie/glim.html) (GLiM) from Hamburg University's Institute for Geology useful for surveying geologic conditions.

Comment: I haven't checked for existing libraries that wrap one or both of these sources -- additions or edits welcome on that front.

Comment: Using an API is a little inconvenient because I'm going to be building a machine learning model. Any alternatives?

Comment: Unfortunately those are proving hard to find. Added GLiM to the answer, which may help you a bit.
You mentioned specific commodities (gold, oil) -- MRDATA has datasets that you can download on specific commodities, but finding them is a challenge (they don't all appear to be grouped together, though https://mrdata.usgs.gov/major-deposits/ may help.)